# How can we connect to Cassandra 4.x using Kundera?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, kundera

We have been using Kundera library in our Java project for connecting to Cassandra database 3.11.11 . The library or jar file that we have been using is com.impetus.kundera.client.kundera-cassandra.3.13.jar
Recently the DBA team in our project migrated DB to Cassandra 4.0.7 version. After migration ,we are not able to connect to the DB.
We were using thrift client factory com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory , port 9061 in persistence.xml.

We have also read in the documentation that Kundera doesn’t support Cassandra 4.x .
https://github.com/Impetus/kundera/wiki/Datastores-Supported

Please help us in identifying the issue here. Please suggest any other alternative that we can use to connect Cassandra 4.x using Java application

Comment: TL;DR; Thrift is gone in 4.0 but deprecated (still present) in 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

Thrift has been deprecated for a very long time and finally [removed](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/e9f8f2efa2ba75f223f31ca6801aff3fe2964745/CHANGES.txt#L1057) with version 4.0. For a Java application it is safe to use a recent version of [DataStax Java-driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/). Other than Thrift, the CQL based Java-driver does have an object mapper, so you probably don't want any other library to include to get JPA support. However, [Spring-Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) is fairly popular and also provides JPA style mapping to multiple back-ends including recent Apache Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

Kundera seems no more supported with a last commit 5 years ago. It did not evolve with the Cassandra technology and as stated by Tibor the support of thrift is long gone.

The **Datastax driver** offers the object mapping you expect:

- [Documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.15/manual/mapper/)
- [Sample Code](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/java-cassandra-driver-from3x-to4x/tree/master/example-4x/src/main/java/com/datastax/samples/objectmapping)

If you are interested in the **Spring Data Cassandra**:

- [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/)
- [Sample Code](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-spring-data-cassandra)

Answer (score 0):

Thrift was deprecated in Cassandra about 8 years ago, replaced by CQL all the way back to 2011 ([CASSANDRA-1703](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1703)). Drivers based on the Thrift API were retired a long time including Nate McCall's [Hector](https://github.com/hector-client/hector) in 2015 and Netflix's [Astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax) in 2016.

Cassandra 2.2 stopped using Thrift in 2015 ([CASSANDRA-8358](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8358), [CASSANDRA-9319](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9319)) and Cassandra 4.0 completely removed Thrift in 2016 ([CASSANDRA-11115](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11115)).

If you read through Kundera's documentation, they [added Cassandra Java driver support in 2014](https://github.com/Impetus/kundera/tree/trunk/src#24-march-2014---kundera-211-released) (Kundera v2.11) so there's really no reason to continue using the Thrift client.

To use the Java driver in Kundera, add the Maven coordinates for the driver to your project. For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>kundera-cassandra-ds-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>
```

The instead of using `ThriftClientFactory`, configure your persistence unit to use the driver with:

```
    <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class"             
        value="com.impetus.kundera.client.cassandra.dsdriver.DSClientFactory" />
```

The Java driver enables you to use CQL for CRUD operations in Kundera. For details, see [Cassandra Java driver support using Kundera](https://github.com/Impetus/kundera/wiki/Datastax-java-driver-support-for-Cassandra-using-Kundera).

Finally, I'm going to echo the recommendation from everyone else. The Kundera library doesn't appear to be actively maintained with the last release going all the way back to June 2018.

We recommend that you migrate your application to using the [Cassandra Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/) natively. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your response . With using kundera-cassandra-ds-driver dependency, I can see its working through sample application and I am able to connect to 4.x Cassandra DB

Comment: Through sample code its working, but its not working while using my application in the project,, I am using JBoss as an application server. Getting below exception on server.